# Replace single quoted string that is separated by comma

Tags: sed

I have sample data as per below

```
'1','2','3,3','4'
```

I am trying to find a sed command to change it to below

```
'1','2','NEW','4'
```

For starter, I tried with below sample

```
1,2,3,4
```

This sed will work

```
's/[^,]*/NEW/'3
```

Result

```
1,2,NEW,4
```

But I cant figure it out how to do with sample data as per below...

```
'1','2','3,3','4'
```

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to use double quotes outside:

```
$ echo "'1','2','3,3','4'" | sed "s/'[^']*'/'NEW'/3"
'1','2','NEW','4'
```

Otherwise, a sequence like `'\''` may be used to close and re-open single quotes around an escaped literal quote:

```
$ echo "'1','2','3,3','4'" | sed 's/'\''[^'\'']*'\''/'\''NEW'\''/3'
'1','2','NEW','4'
```